# angularjs $resource custom get action always calling default getAll method with spring rest controller

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

I am trying to build a web application with angularjs and spring rest. For reference data (Gender, Languages, UserTypes - types that go in combo boxes) I used JPA's single table inheritance (With ReferenceData as base class and Language, Gender, UserType as subclasses).

In my html I need UserType and Gender reference data for combo boxes in Create User screen. I defined a ReferenceDataService in angular JS in the following way:

```
    myapp.factory('ReferenceData', function ($resource) {
       return $resource('app/rest/referenceDatas/:id', {}, {
           'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
           'get': { method: 'GET'},
           'genders': {method:'GET', isArray: true, cache:true},
           'userTypes': {method:'GET', isArray: true, cache:true},
       });
   });
```

In my angularJs UserServiceController I have the following:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, USER_ROLES) {
$routeProvider
.when('/user', {
        templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
        controller: 'UserController',
        resolve:{
            resolvedUser: ['User', function (User) {
                return User.query().$promise;
            }],
            resolvedGender: ['ReferenceData', function (ReferenceData) {
                return ReferenceData.genders().$promise;
            }],
            resolvedUserTypes: ['ReferenceData', function (ReferenceData) {
                return ReferenceData.userTypes().$promise;
            }]
        },
        access: {
            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
        }
    })
});
```

Following is the code snippet from my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/referenceDatas/genders",
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<? extends ReferenceData> genders(){
    return referenceDataRepository.getByType("GENDER");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/referenceDatas/userTypes",
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<? extends ReferenceData> userTypes(){
    return referenceDataRepository.getByType("USER_TYPE");
}
//DEFAULT getALL
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/referenceDatas",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public List<ReferenceData> getAll() {
    log.debug("REST request to get all ReferenceDatas");
    return referenceDataRepository.findAll();
}
```

My problem is everytime I open create user screen Both gender and userType select boxed are filled with all the types from Reference_Data table and logs/debug show that getAll is called everytime i call a custom methods languages and userTypes on referencedata angularjs service.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not passing any parameters in when you are querying. Your `ReferenceData` resource has parameterized URL, and if you do not provide the parameter value when the actual HTTP call is made, it will truncate that part (and hence your `getAll()` call). So, for example, to query genders you can use:

1. Default Params

   ```
    return $resource('app/rest/referenceDatas/:id', {}, {
      'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
      'get': { method: 'GET'},
      'genders': {method:'GET', params: {id:'genders'}, isArray: true, cache:true},
      'userTypes': {method:'GET', isArray: true, cache:true},
   });
   ```
2. Pass the parameters during actual action call:

   ```
   resolvedGender: ['ReferenceData', function (ReferenceData) {
       return ReferenceData.genders({id:'genders'}).$promise;
   }],
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response Prashanth. I made these changes and I see the call to genders (GET http://localhost:8080/app/rest/referenceDatas/genders?cacheBuster=1419006455309 - in chrome console). But it returns 400 Bad Request from server. Do I have to change my request mapping url in Spring controller? something like /rest/referenceDatas/genders/{gender}?

Comment: I don't think any change the Spring Controller URL mapping is required. There is something wrong with the Request sent by the browser. You can check the server logs what part of the request is wrong/invalid.